# Crear un select dependiendo del valor seleccionado en otro

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo este `select`, en el cual los `option` que están en `disabled` son las CATEGORÍAS y dentro de esas categorías hay una letra con número. En este `select` las tengo ordenadas pero me pidieron que cuando seleccione una de esas categorías, en otro `select` me salgan las características de esa categoría. Por ejemplo, cuando seleccione CONDUCTAL, me saliera todas las características de ese conductal en otro `select`, o sea C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6. Y así con todas.

Éste es el código que tengo hasta el momento:

```html
<select class="txtFormulario_PreguntaCategoria" id="txtFormulario_PreguntaCategoria_' + val.idPre + '">
  <option disabled selected></option>
  <option disabled>CONDUCTAL</option>
  <option value="C1">C1</option>
  <option value="C2">C2</option>
  <option value="C3">C3</option>
  <option value="C4">C4</option>
  <option value="C5">C5</option>
  <option value="C6">C6</option>

  <option value="" disabled>ESTRUCTURAL</option>
  <option value="S1">S1</option>
  <option value="S2">S2</option>
  <option value="S3">S3</option>
  <option value="S4">S4</option>
  <option value="S5">S5</option>
  <option value="S6">S6</option>

  <option value="" disabled>ORGANIZATIVA</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">O2</option>
  <option value="03">O3</option>
  <option value="04">O4</option>
  <option value="05">O5</option>
  <option value="06">O6</option>
  <option value="07">O7</option>
  <option value="08">O8</option>
  <option value="09">O9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>

  <option value="" disabled>OTROS FACTORES</option>
  <option value="AF1">AF1</option>
  <option value="AF2">AF2</option>
  <option value="AF3">AF3</option>
  <option value="AF4">AF4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No relacionado con la pregunta en sí: los nombres de categorías que pones como opciones `disabled` deberías ponerlos como `optgroup` (lo cual sería semánticamente más adecuado).

Comment: Relacionado con la pregunta: sería interesante saber si tienes alguna restricción y cómo generas el `select`.

Answer (score 5):

No se si te referías a esto exactamente.

```js
function filter_options(){
 if (typeof $("#choice1").data('options') === "undefined") {
       $("#choice1").data('options', $('#choice2 option').clone());
  }
    var id = $("#choice1").val();
    var options = $("#choice1").data('options').filter('[data-option=' + id + ']');
    $('#choice2').html(options);
}

$(function () {
  //Ejecutar el filtro la primera vez
  filter_options();
    
    //actualizar al cambiar el factor
    $("#choice1").change(function () {
     filter_options();
  });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="choice1">
 <option value="S">ESTRUCTURAL</option>
 <option   value="O">ORGANIZATIVA</option>
 <option  value="AF"  >OTROS FACTORES</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="choice2">
  <option data-option="S"    value="S1">S1</option>
  <option data-option="S"    value="S2">S2</option>
  <option data-option="S"    value="S3">S3</option>
  <option data-option="S"   value="S4">S4</option>
  <option data-option="S"    value="S5">S5</option>
  <option data-option="S"   value="S6">S6</option>
  <option data-option="O"   value="01">01</option>
  <option data-option="O"   value="02">O2</option>
  <option data-option="O"    value="03">O3</option>
  <option data-option="O"   value="04">O4</option>
  <option data-option="O"   value="05">O5</option>
  <option data-option="O"  value="06">O6</option>
  <option data-option="O"   value="07">O7</option>
  <option data-option="O"    value="08">O8</option>
  <option data-option="O"    value="09">O9</option>
  <option data-option="O"   value="10">10</option>
  <option data-option="O"   value="11">11</option>
  <option data-option="AF"    value="AF1">AF1</option>
  <option data-option="AF"   value="AF2">AF2</option>
  <option data-option="AF"    value="AF3">AF3</option>
  <option data-option="AF"   value="AF4">AF4</option>
</select>
```

Lo cual serían dos select, según lo que selecciones en el primero (las cabeceras) te aparecen las opciones correspondientes.

Comment: Gracias por editar la respuesta. Ahora se ve mucho mejor. Por cierto, si completas el [tour] aprenderás más sobre el funcionamiento básico del sitio y ganarás tu primera medalla. Bienvenido al sitio.

Comment: Gracias a ti por el comentario!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias amigos el ejemplo que me hizo el amigo es exacto lo que necesitaba gracias muchisimas gracias

Comment: @PlayTutoAlvarez si esta respuesta resolvió tu problema, márcala como aceptada pulsando en la marca que hay en la parte superior izquierda de la misma.

Answer (score 1):

Ya tienes una solución que vale, voy a poner una alternativa que funcionará aunque **no es ideal**. Podrías usar [`datalist`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/datalist) para tener los valores ordenados y cuando se seleccione una opción en el select, actualizar el valor de la lista para que los valores cambien.

Esta opción no es ideal por varios motivos:

- Asume que los usuarios van a conocer los valores de las opciones (si hay muchos, no se van a mostrar todos como se haría en un `select`).
- No está soportado por todos los navegadores ([fuente](https://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist)).
- `datalist` es una lista de sugerencias, pero los usuarios podrían introducir un valor no sugerido (con un `select` se fuerza a que los valores sean los especificados).

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando (uso JavaScript puro porque no indicaste si usabas jQuery u otra biblioteca):

```js
document.querySelector("#txtFormulario_PreguntaCategoria").addEventListener("change", function() {
  let valores  = document.querySelector("#txtFormulario_PreguntaCategoriaValores");
  valores.setAttribute("list", this.value);
  valores.removeAttribute("disabled");
});
```

```html
<datalist id="conductal">
  <option value="C1">C1</option>
  <option value="C2">C2</option>
  <option value="C3">C3</option>
  <option value="C4">C4</option>
  <option value="C5">C5</option>
  <option value="C6">C6</option>
</datalist>

<datalist id="estructural">
  <option value="S1">S1</option>
  <option value="S2">S2</option>
  <option value="S3">S3</option>
  <option value="S4">S4</option>
  <option value="S5">S5</option>
  <option value="S6">S6</option>
</datalist>

<datalist id="organizativa">
  <option value="01">O1</option>
  <option value="02">O2</option>
  <option value="03">O3</option>
  <option value="04">O4</option>
  <option value="05">O5</option>
  <option value="06">O6</option>
  <option value="07">O7</option>
  <option value="08">O8</option>
  <option value="09">O9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
</datalist>

<datalist id="otros">
  <option value="AF1">AF1</option>
  <option value="AF2">AF2</option>
  <option value="AF3">AF3</option>
  <option value="AF4">AF4</option>
</datalist>

<select class="txtFormulario_PreguntaCategoria" id="txtFormulario_PreguntaCategoria">
  <option disabled selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
  <option value="conductal">CONDUCTAL</option>
  <option value="estructural">ESTRUCTURAL</option>
  <option value="organizativa">ORGANIZATIVA</option>
  <option value="otros">OTROS FACTORES</option>
</select>

<input id="txtFormulario_PreguntaCategoriaValores" list="" disabled />
```